# Linux, Saving data from old HD (connection randomly drops)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

Background:

I have an old HD which I am trying to save data from (important, not so urgent). I am using a SATA adapter (& external power source) to connect the HD to my laptop. `lsusb` calls my adapter 'ID 05e3:0718 Genesys Logic, Inc. IDE/SATA Adapter'. The adapter works, I have used it with another drive at great speeds without any hitches.

Here is the behaviour of the HD in question:

I power it on, wait. I plug the USB in. After a while, linux recognizes it, I can mount it, and browser through the data. All data is intact, however the access is extremely slow (kb/s range). I try to use rsync to start my backup `rsync -aP path1 path2`. It works for a good while then suddenly I get 'the file has vanished' messages. The drive is suddenly no longer mounted, it isn't recognized, it doesn't exist. This also happens if I do not access the drive at all after mounting it. Unpluging and pluging back in the USB adapter (without powering down the drive) makes linux recognize it again. Then I repeat the process (very arduous).

My Question:

Is there a way to remove my problems, or at least automate the 'restarting' procedure.

dmesg output:

```
[ 6378.319663] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
[ 6378.338124] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0718
[ 6378.338135] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[ 6378.338141] usb 3-2: Product: USB Storage
[ 6378.338146] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 000000000033
[ 6378.339121] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 6378.339479] scsi26 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[ 6379.342076] scsi 26:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WDC WD50 00AAKS-00V1A0    0016 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 6379.342946] sd 26:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 6379.343689] sd 26:0:0:0: [sdb] 976773164 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465 GiB)
[ 6379.344240] sd 26:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 6379.344264] sd 26:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 6379.344761] sd 26:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 6379.344769] sd 26:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 6379.351684] sd 26:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 6379.351693] sd 26:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 6379.406202]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3
[ 6379.407815] sd 26:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 6379.407819] sd 26:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 6379.407821] sd 26:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

I can then access the `sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3` in question.

After the drive dies:

```
[ 6922.219418] systemd-hostnamed[4412]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[ 6923.753466] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 28
[ 6923.811243] scsi 27:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 6923.811249] scsi 27:0:0:0: [sdb] killing request
[ 6923.811283] scsi 27:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[ 6923.811285] scsi 27:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[ 6923.811288] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 6923.811290] scsi 27:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[ 6923.811291] Read(10): 28 00 1e ec 26 18 00 00 f0 00
[ 6923.811299] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 518792728
[ 6923.811302] quiet_error: 258 callbacks suppressed
[ 6923.811305] Buffer I/O error on device sdb3, logical block 6278680
[ 6923.811308] Buffer I/O error on device sdb3, logical block 6278681
[ 6923.811309] Buffer I/O error on device sdb3, logical block 6278682
[ 6923.811311] Buffer I/O error on device sdb3, logical block 6278683
[ 6923.811313] Buffer I/O error on device sdb3, logical block 6278684
[ 6923.811316] Buffer I/O error on device sdb3, logical block 6278685
[ 6923.811318] Buffer I/O error on device sdb3, logical block 6278686
[ 6923.811320] Buffer I/O error on device sdb3, logical block 6278687
[ 6923.811325] Buffer I/O error on device sdb3, logical block 6278688
[ 6923.811328] Buffer I/O error on device sdb3, logical block 6278689
[ 6923.811441] scsi 27:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 6923.811445] scsi 27:0:0:0: [sdb] killing request
[ 6923.811707] scsi 27:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[ 6923.811710] scsi 27:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[ 6923.811712] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 6923.811714] scsi 27:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[ 6923.811715] Read(10): 28 00 1e ec 27 08 00 00 f0 00
[ 6923.811723] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 518792968
[ 6924.066187] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
[ 6924.084065] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0718
[ 6924.084075] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[ 6924.084081] usb 3-2: Product: USB Storage
[ 6924.084085] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 000000000033
[ 6924.084847] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 6924.085081] scsi28 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[ 6945.847454] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
[ 6945.864597] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88017f9a1680
[ 6945.864608] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88017f9a16c0
[ 6956.496837] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 29
[ 6956.799664] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
[ 6956.817743] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0718
[ 6956.817754] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[ 6956.817759] usb 3-2: Product: USB Storage
[ 6956.817763] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 000000000033
[ 6956.818457] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 6956.818590] scsi29 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
```

I have no idea were to begin, anything at all would be immensely appreciated.

p.s. I have placed a heavy-duty fan infront of the drive to stop it from overheating, just in case

Comment: Unbind the USB driver and rebind it, this will do the same as an unplug-plug cycle.

Answer (score 0):

USB adaptors often suck. You're better off connecting it locally. If that's clearly not an option, then we need to *work around* the drive being unreliable

There's two different approaches I would consider taking here, both of which assume the unreliability of the drive.

Firstly gnu ddrescue (not the other, older ddrescue) to do a full drive backup.

***USE A LOGFILE***

That way, it'll pick up where it stopped, and keep backing up. It'll also fix up any corruption in the next pass. Mount the rescued drive in kpartx and do a file level backup.

The second would be to do a file level copy with rsync - I don't remember the settings offhand, but I believe -r for recursive and -P for keeping partial files would be necessary.

Both these approaches should work alright, but not as well as plugging in the drive directly with a known good cable to an appropriate, native interface.